# Help with mysql join

Tags: mysql, join

This is my statement for me to pull all the data of my users' friends that they have added:

```
$q = $dbc -> prepare("SELECT a.* FROM accounts a INNER JOIN friends fr ON (a.id = fr.friend_id) WHERE fr.id = ?");
$q -> execute(array($details['id']));
```

Now this is basically where the id matches in the friends table, pull the friends id and all the relevant data with it.

I am trying to implement a friends online page as well, how would I also test to see if a column in accounts for the friend_id matches a certain criterion?

This is how I pull all the users that are online...

```
$online_users = time() - 900;
$q = $dbc -> prepare("SELECT * FROM accounts WHERE last_active > ? && id != ? ORDER BY id");
$q -> execute(array($online_users, $details['id']));
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT a.*
  FROM accounts AS a
  JOIN friends  AS f ON (a.id = f.friend_id)
 WHERE f.id = ?
   AND a.last_active > ?
 ORDER BY id
```

You don't need to repeat the condition on `a.id` since the join enforces it.

Comment: I am guessing the OP wants the online friends of the current user, what you have suggested will check if the current user is online. You would have to do another join to the `accounts` table to check if friend is online, I guess.